What is arXiv++, and who is behind it?
I have just learned of the existence of arXiv++ via an email, whose main content was:

The summary of your paper "Critical spin chains and loop models with $U(n)$ symmetry" has just received its first visitor on arXiv++.


arXiv++ is a free and non-profit browser extension that provides a paper summary and a chat system on top of every arXiv paper page. It is meant for research and educational purposes only.

While having AI-generated paper summaries is of doubtful value, the chat and commenting system is a sorely missing feature in arXiv. Before using it, I would like to know a bit more about arXiv++:

Who built it?
How is it funded?
Who owns the comments that I might write there?
Are there plans to enable MathJax?
Is there some form of moderation? Upvotes and downvotes?
Do authors have a special status when chatting on their own papers? Are they alerted when someone posts a comment?
Can I follow articles?


Chrome dev store says the legal entity is "TricepsAI 60 Rue François 1er Paris 75008 FR". There's also a Dun & Bradstreet number

Where did the mail come from?

@BernhardDöbler: The mail was from arxivpp@tricepsai.com , signed by "Marie from arXiv++", who is most probably a robot.

"the chat and commenting system is a sorely missing feature in arXiv.": This seems to be a rather controversial claim, as the answers and comments on this question show.

You might add: What information does it harvest from users?

There is some information from a claimed arXiv employee in this thread on /r/physics. arXiv is evidently not thrilled about this. Related, there is also something called alphaxiv that is similarly concerning.

Honestly, having practically no hard information but lots of promises, and a mandatory login with your google identity seems scammy. Not to mention that chat and AI needs some infrastructure beyond just an extension.

@MisterMiyagi The reviews for the Chrome and Firefox extensions don't inspire much confidence either. I also like how the extension is marketed as "free and non-profit" but making it open-source (which could go a long way to alleviate concerns) would apparently be one step too far.
